# JPlayer Audio Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, jplayer

I'm attempting to have JPlayer play an audio clip on a specific event, but I'm getting some finicky results.  Sometimes the audio doesn't play back, sometimes the audio stutters on the first 1/4 second, and sometimes after playback a repeat attempt plays the audio clip, but starting near the end.  The code I'm using looks like:

The setup:

```
$("#div").jPlayer({ready: function (){
       $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
          mp3: "./test.mp3"
       });
    }, swfPath: "/dir/", preload: "auto"
});
```

Event Fired:

```
$('#div').jPlayer("play", 0);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and maybe an idea of a better way (different plugin, or none altogether) to achieve the result would be awesome.

Thank you!

Side Note:
Main end platform is the Ipad (Safari), but cross-browser support would be the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) to playback the audio file.  It's been giving consistent results for all of the playbacks I've tested.  Also, it works on many browsers, so it fits my needs just fine.